# Error inflating class TextView - AutoCompleteTextView inside TextInputLayout crashing. Can TextInputLayout handle textview inside it?

Tags: android, android-adapter

Error inflating class TextView - AutoCompleteTextView inside TextInputLayout crashing. Can TextInputLayout handle textview inside it?

**Setting adapter**

```
    mRootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_buddy, container, false);
    mContext = this.getContext();
    mAdapter = new AddBuddyAutoCompleteAdapter(mContext, R.layout.add_buddy_auto_complete_drop_down, mBuddyList);
    mAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteBuddySearch);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**Add_buddy_auto_comolete_drop_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteBuddyPic"
    android:src="@drawable/members6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/autoCompleteBuddyPic"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteBuddyEmail" />
```

**fragment_add_buddy.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/addBuddySearchTitle"
    android:id="@+id/addBuddyEmailField"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />-->


   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:theme="@style/addBuddy">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteBuddySearch"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addBuddyEmailField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<!--<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Nick Name"
    android:id="@+id/addBuddyNickNameView" />-->

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:theme="@style/addBuddy">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addBuddyNickName"
        android:hint="Nick name"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relationshipSpinner"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/relationshipArray"
    android:dropDownSelector="#06a5da" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/invite"
    android:id="@+id/addBuddySendInvite"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**GetViewMethod**

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    if(convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }
    Log.d("XXX", mSuggestions.get(position).mEmail+" "+position);
    //TextView email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteBuddyEmail);
    //email.setText((CharSequence) mSuggestions.get(position).mEmail);
    return row;
}
```

Crash details:

```
> 03-18 09:17:36.304 4552-4552/com.tracoy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
>                                                           android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error
> inflating class TextView
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                               at com.tracoy.adapters.AddBuddyAutoCompleteAdapter.getView(AddBuddyAutoCompleteAdapter.java:43)
>                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
>                                                               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1188)
>                                                               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
>                                                               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1115)
>                                                               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:524)
>                                                               at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1081)
>                                                               at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:956)
>                                                               at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:938)
>                                                               at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                            Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color:
> type=0x2
>                                                               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
>                                                               at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:499)
>                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
>                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
>                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
>                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
>                                                               at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
>                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
>                                                               at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
>                                                               at com.tracoy.adapters.AddBuddyAutoCompleteAdapter.getView(AddBuddyAutoCompleteAdapter.java:43) 
>                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267) 
>                                                               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1188) 
>                                                               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244) 
>                                                               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1115) 
>                                                               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:524) 
>                                                               at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1081) 
>                                                               at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:956) 
>                                                               at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:938) 
>                                                               at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285) 
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody help me on this?
Thanks you!

Answer (score -1):

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View row;
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_file_name, container, false);
Log.d("XXX", mSuggestions.get(position).mEmail+" "+position);
AutoCompleteTextView email = (AutoCompleteTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteBuddyEmail);
email.setText((CharSequence) mSuggestions.get(position).mEmail);
return row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
It cannot be AutoCompleteTextView.
Because AutoCompleteTextView is associated with an adapter and another xml file for dropdown.
That xml file has textview.
But the problem is Error inflating class TextView

Comment: When I had this problem, all I did to fix it was remove the android:drawableLeft statement. It turns out that assigning an image to an AutoCompleteTextView on pre-Lollipop devices causes the problem. On my Lollipop phone, it works fine.